# C# trial and error method for correct/wrong filepath

Tags: c#, .net

I am using VS 2005 (.net version > 2.0+) to create a windows application.

In my application I give relative path to access the file.
the file might exist in any of the known folders (say 2 in number) images1, images2, I need to check out which filepath is correct and which isn't, using some if conditions and bool variables. accordingly I need to point and load that image in my form.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach (string folder in folders)
  if (File.Exist(folder + filename)
     dosomething
```

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the `Path.Combine` and `File.Exists` methods.

Using LINQ:

```
var actualPath = possiblePaths.Select(p => Path.Combine(p, relativePath))
                              .FirstOrDefault(File.Exists);
```

Comment: LINQ's not available in .Net 2.0 is it?

Comment: You're right; I missed that line.  You'll need to convert that to a `for` loop with an `if`.

Answer (score 0):

I sense this is related to [C# How to derive the relative-filepath of file located in grand-parent folder?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509965/c-how-to-derive-the-relative-filepath-of-file-located-in-grand-parent-folder/4510076#4510076)
Please read the responses.

A trial and error method would prove to be expensive

Comment: yes .. its a sequel of that question. btw .. How can I handle both debug/release mode .. giving same file path (relative path)? so came to conclusion to use trial and error, if I don't get the proper filepath in first attempt(assuming I am in debug folder) I would go for accessing parent folders and there by successively pointing to the required file :)

Comment: The key lies in packaging the application. On post build create folders. I have updated the original answer.

Comment: I have a strange requirement, I must clarify, My primary intention is not to publish/deploy the project but to be able to run in both debug and release mode (opening the solution)

Comment: @infant programmer: are you familiar with pre-processor directives?   I don't know if this is helpful in your situation or not, but you can do something like #if DEBUG ... <Code that is applicable to DEBUG build> ... #else ... <Code that is applicable to non-DEBUG build> ... #endif, and only the applicable code will only be processed according to the configuration.  (I'm not sure how to format comments, so I apologize if this is hard to make sense of)

Comment: @Steven, hey thats incredible, Well I got what you precisely mean :) well I think I can assign the variable the suitable path according to #If condition :)))) ok .. I will just try it out :)

Comment: @Steven, why didn't u post it as an answer? :)

Comment: @IP: It was reading your comment here that made me think that might be what you were looking for, but I guess maybe I should have gone ahead and made it an answer...I'm still trying to figure out the best practices on this site :)      Has that given you what you need?

Comment: @Steven, well. I am glad to see the alternative techniques. Its always been recommended to software programmer to know different techniques of same method :)

Comment: @Steven, you still can post it as an answer (as it is a valid one) and gain upvotes (atleast from me) moreover, an answer drives more attention than comments, A person who is seeking answer may not read ur comment. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check for the existence of a file with the System.IO.File.Exists(string path) method.   If it's helpful, there's also an equivalent System.IO.Directory.Exists(string path).

*ETA the following from comments*:

=======================================================================

[Preprocessor directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ed8yd1ha.aspx) also provide a means by which code can be compiled conditionally based on the configuration.   For example something like this will give you one type of behavior with a "debug" build and a different type of behavior with a "release" (well, any non-debug) build:

```
public void DoStuff()
{

#if DEBUG
    // The stuff in this block only happens for a DEBUG build
#else
    // The stuff in this block only happens for a non-debug build
#endif

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [System.IO.File.Exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx) where you feed it the path(s) and filename, if it returns true, the file is there.

Comment: ok :) thanks :) I will make use of your valuable suggestion.:)

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need to make use of [`File.Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx).  Using this along with [`Directory.Exists()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists.aspx) you can traverse the file system and load the appropriate file from the appropriate location